# mongoose get _id field of a found document

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to get the `_id` field of specific employee by `req.body.name` :

```
const requestVacation = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const employee = await Employee.find({ nameAR: req.body.name }).select('_id')

    const vacation = new Vacation({
      employeeId: employee._id,
      type: req.body.type,
      startDate: req.body.startDate,
      endDate: req.body.endDate,
      numberOfHours: req.body.numberOfHours,
    });
    await vacation.save();
    res.status(200).json("vacation has been requested successfully");

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(404).json(err);
  }
};
```

the `employee` variable will return this :

```
[ { _id: new ObjectId("630ba65261c73f3c8afc5c8c") } ]
```

but i only want the `_id` **value** to save it as `employeeId` in vacation collection, so how can i get the `_id` value ?

i **tried** :

```
employee._id
```

but it returns `undefined`

i also **tried** :

```
    const employee = await Employee.find({ nameAR: req.body.name }, { _id: 1 });
```

it returns the same result, how to get the `_id` value out of it

Comment: Use `const employee = await Employee.findOne({ nameAR: req.body.name }).select('_id')`. And then: `employee._id`

Comment: please read the post, it returns ```undefined```

Comment: answer by @nimrodserok is to change the function from find to findOne 

find returns an array of records while findOne get the 1st match value

Comment: @aasemshoshari or change it to employee[0]._id

Comment: oh, sorry for carelessness and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning an array from the DB with `find`. You can access the _id with `employee[0]._id` or use `findOne`, and it will return an object to be accessed with `employee._id`